# XOR linear equation system solver in Python

Tags: python, equation, xor

I have n rows and n+1 columns matrix and need to construct such system
For example matrix is

```
x4 x3 x2 x1 result
1  1  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  1
0  1  0  1  1
1  0  1  1  0
```

Then equation will be (+ is XOR)

```
x4+x3+x1=0
x4+x2=1
x3+x1=1
x4+x2+x1=0
```

I need to return answer as list of x1,.....
How can we do it in python?

Comment: I don't see how the matrix is related to the equations. What are `x4`, `x3`, etc.?

Comment: yeah sorry, updated

Comment: I don't know numpy well, but I'll bet you can do it easily with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the Python interface [pyz3](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) of Microsoft's Z3 solver:

```
from z3 import *

def xor2(a, b):
    return Xor(a, b)

def xor3(a, b, c):
    return Xor(a, Xor(b, c))

#  define Boolean variables
x1 = Bool('x1')
x2 = Bool('x2')
x3 = Bool('x3')
x4 = Bool('x4')

s = Solver()

#  every equation is expressed as one constraint
s.add(Not(xor3(x4, x3, x1)))
s.add(xor2(x4, x2))
s.add(xor2(x3, x1))
s.add(Not(xor3(x4, x2, x1)))

#  solve and output results
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

Result:

```
sat
[x3 = False, x2 = False, x1 = True, x4 = True]
```

You can install the package as:

```
python -m pip install z3-solver
```

---

**Alternative solution**

You could also make use of the Python wrapper of the [SAT solver](https://www.borealisai.com/research-blogs/tutorial-9-sat-solvers-i-introduction-and-applications/) [cryptominisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat). This solver has built-in capability to solve a system of xor clauses. The comments explain how to install the necessary Python package *pycryptosat*.
The problem to be solved is expressed as array of variable lists and xor results. There are certainly more elegant ways to store such problems.
The solver returns a (potentially long) tuple of truth values, one for every variable.

```
#
#  How to install pycryptosat, the python wrapper of cryptominisat?
#  ================================================================
#  For Windows:
#  Download pycryptosat binary .whl from
#  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycryptosat
#  \Python38\Scripts>pip install pycryptosat-0.6.1.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
#
#  Note: It is essential that the downloaded wheel file fits your installed ptyhon version
#        In my case cp38 for python 3.8 and 64 bits.
#        Otherwise, the pip install will abort with failure
#
#  For Unix, a simple "pip install pycroptosat" should suffice

import pycryptosat
from pycryptosat import Solver 

s = Solver(threads=1)

var_names = ["x4", "x3", "x2", "x1"]
var_id = [4, 3, 2, 1]
dic_id_name = {id: var_names[index] for index, id in enumerate(var_id)}

problem = [
    #  x4 x3 x2 x1 result
    [[1, 1, 0, 1], 0],
    [[1, 0, 1, 0], 1],
    [[0, 1, 0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0, 1, 1], 0]
  ]

#  Translate problem into set of xor clauses
for xor in problem:
    clause = [var_id[index] for index, value in enumerate(xor[0]) if value == 1]
    rhs = (xor[1] == 1)
    #  add_xor_clause() expects a list of variable IDs as first parameter.
    #  Second parameter is the right-hand-side of the xor expression.
    #  print(f"xor clause {clause} {rhs}")
    s.add_xor_clause(clause, rhs)

sat, solution = s.solve()
    
print(f"sat: {sat}")

if (sat):
    print(f"solution:")
    for id, name in sorted(dic_id_name.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]):
        print(f"{name} = {solution[id]}")
else:
    print("No solution. Sorry!")
```

**Resulting output:**

```
sat: True
solution:
x1 = True
x2 = False
x3 = False
x4 = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn Gauss, can be also used for XOR. Then write a gauss python program

Comment: This answer is significantly lacking in details, it should just be a comment. I know you don't have enough rep to comment, but that doesn't mean you should post a poor answer instead.