# Is there a function to solve system of xor equations with bytes for python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, equation, gaussian

I have 3 xor equations involving bytes. Each byte is represented as an integer from 0-255. I am using ^ to represent bitwise xor in the following equation.

a ^ b=244

b ^ c=85

a ^ c=161

I want to solve it such that i get a=220, b=40 and c=125

Is there a trivial way to solve this using common packages such as numpy/scipy etc?

Else, ive seen that gaussian elimination is the common method to solve for system of equations. however most examples were in bits hence GE is done modulo 2. as xor is interchangeable eith + in gf(2), however will this be extendable to my case where i am handling bytes? do i have to split the bytes into bits and solve using GE with modulo 2 for each bit in the byte or can i do the same on the bytes but modulo 256 instead? i fail to see how this is possible given that GE solves for equations with addition however bitwise xor for bytes can result in both addition and subtraction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XOR linear equation system solver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607759/xor-linear-equation-system-solver-in-python)

Comment: its only for bits though so i have to split my byte down into bits and solve? i was wondering if there was a way to solve bytewise